# Is there a set whose power set is countably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Does there exist a set whose power set is countably infinite?

I know for sure that if a set has a finite number of elements, then its power set must have a finite number of elements, and if a set has an infinite number of elements, then its power set must have an infinite number of elements (possibly uncountably many elements). Then, there must not exist something like that (which I stated at first). Am I right? Please someone clarify it.

Comment: @Ari: While your edit is probably a good addition here, I think that in cases like this at least receiving some kind of a green light from the OP is preferable.

Comment: @bof : that's what was trying to say. Thanks. (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for your answer, I meant to say what bof wrote, sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: (I generally don't like to answer questions that I've answered in the past, but I will deviate from my recent habit of deleting the answer, since this one is quite different from the answer I wrote on the duplicate, and from the other answers here as well.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No.

Let's call a cardinal $\kappa$ a *strong limit cardinal*, if whenever $A$ is a set of cardinality strictly less than $\kappa$, also $\mathcal P(A)$ has cardinality $<\kappa$.

It is easy to see that $\aleph_0$ is a strong limit cardinal, exactly because everything smaller is finite, and the power set of a finite set is finite.

Now we can prove a general theorem:

> Suppose that $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal. There is no set $A$ such that $|\mathcal P(A)|=\kappa$.

*Proof.* Recall Cantor's theorem, for all sets $A$, $|A|<|\mathcal P(A)|$. If $|\mathcal P(A)|=\kappa$, then $|A|<\kappa$. But now by virtue of being a strong limit cardinal, $|\mathcal P(A)|<\kappa$ as well. $\square$

---

In particular, it means there is no set whose power set is countably infinite.

Comment: Could you please check that my answer after being edited is correct now? It seems fine to me and if it's not wrong anymore, I'm going to leave it be.

Comment: The edited answer is okay. It's not very well written (it feels like you wrote it under stress of "I want to do it quickly and not get more downvotes"), but the content is correct.

Comment: @bof: You're probably right. But I think we should wait for the OP's response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked this question out of curiosity. After your answer, I found that I need to learn a lot before asking such questions.

Comment: Is the non-existence of strong limit cardinals other than $|\mathbb N|$ equivalent to the generalized continuum hypothesis?

Comment: How does the proof of "everything smaller than $\aleph_0$ is finite" go?

Comment: @user159517: Uhh... by definition?

Comment: @Jack: The non-existence of other strong limit cardinals is equivalent to $0=1$. In other words, there are others, and to some extent it is "correct" to say that "most cardinals" are strong limit cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I think I see. So even if we assume GCH, we can repeatedly take $\mathcal P^n(\mathbb N)$ (power set of power set of... etc, $n$ times), without "skipping over" any cardinals, but there's a smallest cardinal that's greater than all of those which will be a strong limit cardinal? Is that approximately correct?

Comment: @Jack: Correct. GCH has nothing to do with that, though. But if you do assume GCH, then every limit cardinal is a strong limit cardinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you give me some reference to read about strong limit cardinal, GCH etc. (As a under-grad student, afraid to ask my prof...)

Comment: @user467365: Well, that depends on what exactly you are studying now. Is it an intro course, are you using a book, what topics have/will you covered, etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : No no, I just started my first year, that question I asked is totally came to my mind while doing a competitive exam question!  And just studying Real Analysis, Linear Algebra, Number theory, etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I am just asking for a *good* reference book on that topic, that's all. I will try to read, if I can not understand, I might hold a year, then try again to read that. Thanks

Comment: @user467365: I think Just and Weese's Discovering Modern Set Theory is pretty nice and might suit you. Jech's Set Theory is also a standard reference. These topics, to some extent might be covered in more accessible books, but I don't know. Maybe in Enderton or Goldrei. There is also Jech and Hrbacek's Introduction to Set Theory. Again, recommending a good book is like buying a good suit, it needs to fit *you*, and that depends on the shape of knowledge in your head.

Comment: @user467365: You might be interested in http://karagila.org/2016/the-five-whs-of-set-theory/

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks a lot! I am reading it now!

Comment: @user159517 Given a subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$, its increasing enumeration gives us a bijection between $A$ and an initial segment of $\mathbb N$. That is, any subset of $\mathbb N$ is either finite or has the same size as $\mathbb N$. If $|B|\le|\mathbb N|$ then, by definition, there is an injection from $B$ into $\mathbb N$, and therefore there is a bijection between $B$ and some subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$. It follows in particular that if $|B|<|\mathbb N|$, then $B$ is finite.

Answer (score 11):

The size of the power set of a set is larger than the size of the set itself. This statement is called Cantor's theorem.

If $n$ is finite, then the size of its power set is $2^n$ which is finite. So, the desired set has to be infinite. But then an infinite set has to have a set of the size of natural numbers (countable) inside it.

By Cantor's theorem again, the size of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is therefore greater than the size of $\mathbb{N}$ itself. This means that the size of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ has to be strictly larger than countable, i.e. uncountable.

Since the set you are looking for has a set of the size of natural numbers inside it, its cardinality must be strictly larger than countable. This shows that such a set whose power set is countable cannot exist.

Comment: The answer is right but the reason is wrong. CH isn't part of ZFC. Try [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)

Comment: can you please explain a little bit. I am not familiar with ZFC and continum hypothesis.

Comment: No, check my comment again.

Answer (score 1):

No, and this follows from these three observations:

- A finite set has a finite power set.
- $|\mathcal P(A)|$ is is always larger than $|A|$ (Cantor's theorem).
- $\aleph_0$ is the smallest non-finite cardinal number.